# Controlling Visibility of ListView Footer

Tags: android

Scenario: Keep reference to footer in activity. set footer visibility to GONE.  add footer to ListView.  ListView.setAdapter(adapter).

Now how can I get footer to show? I tried setting visibility back VISIBLE, but it does not show. What else exactly needs to be done for this footer to display.  I don't want to reset adapter again.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the following functions :

```
listView.addFooterView(footerView)
listView.removeFooterView(footerView)
```